# Most efficient way to find distance of points from inner border of polygons

Tags: polygon, arcgis-pro, distance, proximity

Problem: I have a points layer and a polygons layer. I have already used the Near tool to find the distances from points to the closest polygons, but it gives me a 0 value for all points that intersect with polygons.

Goal: For all points that overlap with polygons (i.e. when a point is "inside" a polygon), I want to to find the distance from each point to the closest inner border of the polygon, as a negative value. This turns out to be more complicated than initially expected, as the Near tool does not allow for negative distances (distance inside of the polygon border). Instead, it says that all points within the polygons are 0 units away. My desired result is one table with all distances to polygons (positive and negative). Creating negative buffers inside polygons works, but I would like to get exact distances. One way I think I could do this is as follows:

1. Select by location: select all points intersecting with polygons.
2. Use Polygon to Line to transform polygons into lines.
3. Use the Near tool to calculate point distances to the closest line segments.
4. Add field to the resulting table. This new field will be the distance to the closest line, multiplied by -1 (to specify that the distance is inside a border.)
5. Join the above table to the table containing positive distances (where points are outside of the polygon borders).

Is this the most efficient way to do this? Is there another way that retains the original polygons, or a way I can find all distances from borders in one step, regardless of whether or not the point intersects with a polygon or not?

Comment: Yes your approach is sound, convert the polygons to polylines then run the near tool on that.